# LCD BENQ monitor brightness

Tags: display, lcd, brightness, contrast

I have BENQ 15 inch LCD monitor. When I turn on monitor, contrast or brightness dialog is automatically displayed on screen and I cannot remove this dialog. If I increase brightness, automatically decrease brightness. Most of the time on/off, contrast button of monitor do not work. What should I do?

Comment: RMA if it's still under warranty?

Comment: No, it's not under warranty.

Comment: Further suggestion please!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace it. There's nothing much you can do, tbh. Maybe hit the reste-factory-settings on the OSD, if it's there